# Verifying which 5-strings form valid words

Tags: string-manipulation

```
words = getWordsFromPi[200];

For[i = 0, i < Length[words], i++, 
  if[DictionaryWordQ[StringJoin[words[[i]]], 
    Insert[list, words[[i]]]]]]
```

`words` is a list of lists that contain 5-character elements. My goal with the  For-loop is to check which 5-characters, when joined together in string, create a valid word recognized by `DictionaryWordQ`.

When I find a valid word it, I want to accumulate it in another list.

I do not know where to go from here.

```
getWordsFromPi[n_] := 
Map[StringJoin, 
Partition[
Map[FromCharacterCode, 
 Flatten@ToExpression@
   StringSplit[Delete[StringPartition[ToString[N[Pi, n]], 2], 1], 
    ","]], 5]];

words = getWordsFromPi[10000];
Select[words, DictionaryWordQ]
```

The issue I am having now is that the DictionaryWordQ built-in function isn't working how I wanted it to. When you execute the code above, you will obtain this list:

```
{"H-W\.00B", "\.00\.05D
G", "\.00C3\.03\"", "XX\.00NE", "\.00:L\.07:", "\.00\.1d`\.07S", "F\
\.00E\\R", "\.00\"\.0fW\.16", "\.00P\.1f7Z", "\.00%\[RawEscape]b'"}
```

Clearly none of these are the English words that I am looking for. In fact, I expected the list to be empty, but instead I obtained this nonsense. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Select[words, DictionaryWordQ]` should generate the subset of `words` that are dictionary words.

Comment: I think you should provide part of your list. Also I would recommend you to use somathing like `Select[words,DictionaryWordQ[StringJoin@#]&]` . But I need this list in order to check if this works

Comment: https://imgur.com/dqOGFrk 

Here is my code. I changed my function to produce a list that already StringJoins ahead of time so now the list is just a list of 5 length strings

Comment: Please copy/paste this code (the getwordsFromPi function) in your question

Comment: @J42161217 Done

Comment: So you are taking every 2 digits like (14,15,92...). But those are NOT all letters in FromCharacterCode. Letters are only `a to z -> 97-122` and `A to Z -> 65-90`. So you should use a better approach using only numbers from 65 to 90

Comment: I see.. It seems like I should somehow filter the list before I call character code so that the list only contains the digits 65-90 in order for DictionaryWordQ to work correctly (albeit the words will be in all caps). How would I filter the list in such a way?

Comment: I posted an answer using modulo. I will post another one with the filter that you ask

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I made a quick-fix using modulo 26 in order to get only letters

```
getWordsFromPi[n_] :=Map[StringJoin,Partition[Map[FromCharacterCode, 
 Mod[Flatten@ToExpression@StringSplit[Delete[StringPartition[ToString[N[Pi, n]],2], 1], ","], 
   26] + 65], 5]];

words = getWordsFromPi[10000];
Select[words, DictionaryWordQ]
```

this returns

> {"GRAVE"}

Here is the second filter that you asked (I prefer the first one)
This only keeps numbers from 65-90 but in order to return some words you need way more digits of Pi...
try it

```
getWordsFromPi[n_] := 
Map[StringJoin, 
Partition[
Map[FromCharacterCode, 
 Select[Flatten@
   ToExpression@
    StringSplit[Delete[StringPartition[ToString[N[Pi, n]], 2], 1],
      ","], 65 <= # <= 90 &]], 5]];

 words = getWordsFromPi[100000];
 Select[words, DictionaryWordQ]
```

100.000 digits return...

> {"ITCHY"}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `N[]` + string trickery, it is better to just use `RealDigits[]` directly.

Using J42161217's two examples:

```
With[{n = 1*^4}, 
     Select[StringJoin /@ Partition[FromCharacterCode[Mod[FromDigits[#], 26] + 65] & /@
            Partition[Rest[First[RealDigits[Pi, 10, n + 1]]], 2], 5], DictionaryWordQ]]
   {"GRAVE"}

With[{n = 1*^5},
     Select[StringJoin /@ Partition[Map[FromCharacterCode, Select[FromDigits /@
            Partition[Rest[First[RealDigits[Pi, 10, n + 1]]], 2], Between[{65, 90}]]], 5],
            DictionaryWordQ]]
   {"ITCHY"}
```